# Is it safe to use Queue with one producer and multiple consumers

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, queue

I need to implement a queue in a multi-threading situation with multiple consumers but only one thread will modify the queue(Enqueue). Is it safe to use the Queue or I should consider using ConcurrentQueue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `Enqueue` and `Dequeue` are operations that modify the queue. So, if there is one thread that calls `Enqueue` and another thread calls `Dequeue`, then the two calls need to be synchronized.

- If you're using the [Queue<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx), the queue is not thread-safe and you need to synchronize the calls by wrapping them in [`lock` statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).
- If you're using the [ConcurrentQueue<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx), the queue is thread-safe and does the synchronization for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using framework 4 or above, then better option would be to use [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) which is specifically designed for Producer/Consumer pattern (it is internally a ConcurrentQueue by default). It allows you to easily coordinate production and consumption among your threads without thinking too much about locks/monitors. Just use [GetConsumingEnumerable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) to consume items without any other manual synchronization effort. [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)